# How can I make a function accept arrays of static size in solidity?

Tags: arrays, solidity

I have a function in the following form

```
function getStraightIndices(uint256[] memory valnums) public pure returns (uint256[5] memory) {
        ...
}
```

and I call it as

```
uint256[13] memory ranknums;
uint256[5] memory straightindices = getStraightIndices(ranknums);
```

which throws `Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint256[13] memory to uint256[] memory requested.` Why is this conversion even necessary and how can I make `getStraightIndices` accept arrays of any fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

The types are different since in the case `uint256[5] memory` the length is hardcoded in the contract's bytecode, while in the case `uint256[] memory` the length is read from memory.

So a function with argument `uint256[] memory` can't accept the fixed length array. You have to work with dynamic ones:

```
uint256[] memory ranknums = new uint256[](13);
uint256[5] memory straightindices = getStraightIndices(ranknums);
```